# Inserting Post Meta From SQL

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb, sql

I'm trying to get post meta to be updated/replaced with $wpdb and running into issues. I have working SQL, but cannot get it work when coding it up for my WP plugin.

**Extra note:**

The post meta being saved is for example is Twitter follower count that I need the number to be saved to the database so I can export the result in a table

Here is my working SQL. When I put this in PHPmyAdmin it updates all post meta:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT wp_posts.ID, 'agency_details_seo_grade', 'test'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' and wp_posts.post_type = 'agencies'";
```

Here is my failed attempt putting it in WP. Nothing happened as a result (no meta changed and no error message):

```
// Failed attempt to put into functions.php
function add_grading_post_meta() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID,'','test2'", $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ($post_id,meta_key,meta_value)"));
}
```

I'm trying to get this working so I can use it with wp_cron before the next step of using it with WP scheduling functions. Any help would be appreciated for this first step, cracking a lot of hours on this project learning PHP.

**Edit:**

Here's 1 more version I tried with no success. I changed it due to @czerspalace comment, coding provided by old Stack Exchange post.

```
function add_grading_post_meta() {
    global $wpdb;

    $twitter_followers = 'agency_details_twitter_followers';
    $twitter_count = 'test3';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES   (%d,'%s',%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = %s";
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_id,$twitter_followers,$twitter_count);
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: What if you add `$wpdb->print_error();` after your prepare statement, what do you see? Your syntax is incorrect. Your `$wpdb->query` should be outside of `prepare` Look here for how to use prepare and query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: @czerspalace I updated with new code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `$wpdb->prepare` is very broken. I honestly don't even know exactly what query you are trying get. The code is so broken I can't even infer what you are trying to do. However, I am guessing you want something like this:

```
$post_id = 1;
$key = 'abc';
$value = 'def';
$qry = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES (%d,%s,%s)";
$qry = $wpdb->prepare(
  $qry,
  $post_id,
  $key,
  $value
);
var_dump($qry);
$wpdb->query($qry);
```

Notice what happens. You create a "format" string with placeholders for you dynamic data. Then you pass that through `prepare` along with the replacement strings for the placeholders, and get back a string that is sent through `query`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, you're the expert here because it was your posts I was reading and trying to decipher for doing this :)

I tried your code above and still didn't see post meta added. Sorry if my 'prepare' code was bad, I posted the SQL though for what I'm trying to do (that worked). Let me know if you need more info if it changes your original answer.

Comment: Also to include to my previous message, I try changing 'key' and 'value' after as well and still no luck.

Comment: The basic idea doesn't change, the `$qry` string would be different.

Comment: If this was resolved then please accept the answer or write up your own answer to keep the site tidy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the customary way to do this in WordPress would be to use `<?php update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value); ?>` as per the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta. It yields shorter code, and the intent of the code is clearer.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, would you care to explain why?